# Find the no. of ways of getting a sum n with all positive integers less than n

Tags: algorithm, math, series

For a given number n, say 2 how many ways can we get a sum 2 using numbers less that 2.

```
1+1 = 2  
so, for 2 - just 1 way.

n = 3   
1+1+1=3  
1+2=3  
so,for 3 - it is 2 ways  
n = 4   
1+1+1+1=4  
1+1+2=4  
1+3=4  
2+2=4  

so, for 4 - it is 4 ways
```

Can there be a generic pattern/solution to this question?

Answer (score 12):

This problem is known as [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), see detail in the referenced link from wiki:

> One way of getting a handle on the partition function involves an
>   intermediate function p(k, n), which represents the number of
>   partitions of n using only natural numbers at least as large as k. For
>   any given value of k, partitions counted by p(k, n) fit into exactly
>   one of the following categories:
>
> ```
> smallest addend is k
> smallest addend is strictly greater than k.
> ```
>
> The number of partitions meeting the first condition is p(k, n − k).
>   To see this, imagine a list of all the partitions of the number n − k
>   into numbers of size at least k, then imagine appending "+ k" to each
>   partition in the list. Now what is it a list of? As a side note, one
>   can use this to define a sort of recursion relation for the partition
>   function in term of the intermediate function, namely
>
> ```
> 1+ sum{k=1 to floor (1/2)n} p(k,n-k) = p(n),
> ```
>
> The number of partitions meeting the second condition is p(k + 1, n)
>   since a partition into parts of at least k that contains no parts of
>   exactly k must have all parts at least k + 1.
>
> Since the two conditions are mutually exclusive, the number of
>   partitions meeting either condition is p(k + 1, n) + p(k, n − k). The
>   recursively defined function is thus:
>
> ```
> p(k, n) = 0 if k > n
>
> p(k, n) = 1 if k = n
>
> p(k, n) = p(k+1, n) + p(k, n − k) otherwise.
> ```

In fact you can calculate all values by [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), to prevent from extra recursive calls.

**Edit:** As unutbu mentioned in his comment, at the end of calculation you should subtract 1 to output the result. I.e. all of the `P` values up to the last step should be calculated as wiki suggests, however at the very in the very end before outputting the result, You should subtract it by `1`.

Comment: And to link this to the OP's way of counting, we must subtract 1 from p(1,n) since the OP is not counting `n` as a partition of `n`.

Comment: @unutbu yes, but the final result should be subtracted from 1, in fact all P(i,j) will be calculated in the way wrote above (in wiki) but for `P(n)` (or P(1,n)) (just output value) it should be subtracted from 1. I'd edited my answer, thanks.